# Class model - setting default value

Tags: c#

When defining the default value, what is the difference between

```
[DefaultValue("member")]
public string Role { get; set; }
```

and

```
public string Role { get; set; } = "member";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is an attribute which can be useful for meta-programming. For example, you might want to remember what the default value is if someone clears an input. It has *nothing* to do with the C# language itself. It does not modify the value of `Role`.

The second actually sets the property's value to 'member' in memory.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

In other words, your first example helps tools (like the Windows Forms Designer) to know what the intended default value for a property is. But it does **nothing** at run-time.

If you want a property to be assigned a default value at run-time, you have to do it yourself, as in the second example you show.